# How can improve my code by skipping unnecessary steps

Tags: python, pandas, date, dictionary

I want to improve my code by removing unnecessary steps, in my code I have 2 lists, dates and values, here is a sample of them

```
dates = ['2022-10-16 17:00:00', '2022-10-16 18:00:00', '2022-10-16 21:00:00', '2022-10-16 22:00:00']

values = [1920.0, 570.0, 1680.0, 900.0]
```

I wanted to separate the dates to morning and evening, for example

```
{'2022-10-16 17:00:00': [1920.0], '2022-10-16 18:00:00': [570.0, 1680.0, 900.0]}
```

i.e all dates with time from 06:00 to 17:00 are considered morning, and from 18:00 to 05:00 are night.

To do that i used pandas df to create an extra column "period"(morning and night), and then created another column, DatePeriod, so I can group all the morning values from the same day, and then went back to a dict, it feels very impractical and unnecessary with dataframe step but i can't think of any other way to that!
Those are the function

```
    def date_value_df(self):
        date = self.date()
        value = self.value()
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date, value)), columns =['DateTime', 'Value'])
        df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        df['Date'] = df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        df['Time'] = df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
        df['period'] =  pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime).dt.hour,
                bins=[0, 5, 17, 23],
                labels=['night', 'morning', 'night'],
                include_lowest=True, ordered= False)
        df['DatePeriod']=df['Date'].astype(str) + '-' + df['period'].astype(str)
        return df
    
    def df_to_shortened_dict(self):
        df = self.date_value_df()
        result_dict = (df.assign(sdatetime=df['DateTime'].astype(str)).groupby('DatePeriod')
                      .agg({"Value": list, ("sdatetime"): "first"})
                      .set_index("sdatetime")["Value"]
                      .to_dict())
        return result_dict
```

How can i achieve this result without having to use dataframe?

```
{'2022-10-16 17:00:00': [1920.0], '2022-10-16 18:00:00': [570.0, 1680.0, 900.0]}
```

Comment: could we make it with pandas series? I think it is better here

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

dates = ['2022-10-16 17:00:00', '2022-10-16 18:00:00', '2022-10-16 21:00:00', '2022-10-16 22:00:00']

values = [1920.0, 570.0, 1680.0, 900.0]

dict_values = dict(morning=None, night=None)


def is_morning(d: str):
    hour = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").hour
    if 6 < hour <= 17:
        return True
    else:
        return False


for index, date in enumerate(dates):
    period = None
    if is_morning(date):
        period = 'morning'
    else:
        period = 'night'

    if dict_values[period] is None:
        dict_values[period] = {date: [values[index]]}
    else:
        key = list(dict_values[period].keys())[0]
        dict_values[period][key].append(values[index])

print(dict_values)
```

print `{'morning': {'2022-10-16 17:00:00': [1920.0]}, 'night': {'2022-10-16 18:00:00': [570.0, 1680.0, 900.0]}}`